# InsertOnSubmit gives this error. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, parameters, insertonsubmit

InsertOnSubmit gives error "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'entity' of table.InsertOnSubmit(chalet)". How do I fix this?

This is my code.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        chalet hetHuis = new chalet();

        hetHuis.Naamcode = naamcode.Text;
        hetHuis.Persoonaantal = Convert.ToInt32(personenaantal.Text);
        hetHuis.Klasse = Convert.ToString(klasse.SelectedItem);

        db.chalets.InsertOnSubmit();
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

it gives the error at db.chalets.InsertOnSubmit();

Comment: Have you tried `db.chalets.InsertOnSubmit(hetHuis);`?

Comment: I hope your visual studio _IntelliSense_ is working and you are able to look up what parameter/s a method requires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the entity in `db.chalets.InsertOnSubmit();` like `db.chalets.InsertOnSubmit(hetHuis);`